# Line spacing in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox that is filled with the result of a SqlServer query on vb.net. The result joins all items horizontally and when reaching the richtextbox margin it will wrap the line.

Code:

```
   'Function of loading data into Datagridview

   Private Sub entregue()
    dgv1.Rows.Clear()
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim consultando As New frm_aguarde_consultando
    consultando.Show()
    ' Set cursor as hourglass
    Application.DoEvents()

    Dim ano, mes, dia As Integer
    Dim var1data, var2data As Date
    Dim dinicio, dfim As String

    var1data = DateTimePicker1.Value '.ToString.Substring(0, 10)
    dia = var1data.Day
    mes = var1data.Month
    ano = var1data.Year
    dinicio = ano & "-" & mes & "-" & dia

    var2data = DateTimePicker2.Value
    dia = var2data.Day
    mes = var2data.Month
    ano = var2data.Year
    dfim = ano & "-" & mes & "-" & dia

    Using sqlcoon As SqlConnection = GetConnectionsql()
        Dim READER As SqlDataReader
        'ENTREGUE
        Try
            sqlcoon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select MOV_IDENTIFICACAO,MOV_PROTOCOLO,MOV_DATADOC,MOV_SITUACAO,MOV_DATAENTREGA,MOV_HORAENTREGA,MOV_SITEND_CODIGO
                    from movimento where MOV_DATADOC = '" & dinicio & "' 
                    AND MOV_CLI_CODIGO = '" & txtcod.Text & "' AND MOV_SITUACAO = '" & "E" & "'
                    AND CAST(MOV_DATAENTREGA AS DATE) = '" & dfim & "' "


            Dim COMMAND As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, sqlcoon)

            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            While READER.Read
                Dim MOV_IDENTIFICACAO = READER("MOV_IDENTIFICACAO")
                Dim MOV_DATADOC = READER("MOV_DATADOC")
                Dim MOV_DATAENTREGA = READER("MOV_DATAENTREGA")
                Dim MOV_PROTOCOLO = READER("MOV_PROTOCOLO")
                Dim MOV_SITUACAO = READER("MOV_SITUACAO")
                Dim MOV_SITEND_CODIGO = READER("MOV_SITEND_CODIGO")
                dgv1.Rows.Add(MOV_IDENTIFICACAO, MOV_PROTOCOLO, MOV_DATADOC, MOV_SITUACAO, MOV_DATAENTREGA, MOV_SITEND_CODIGO)

            End While
            READER.Close()
            sqlcoon.Close()

            For Each linha In dgv1.Rows
                Dim altura As Integer = 17
                linha.height = altura

            Next

            If dgv1.Rows.Count >= 0 Then
                ' Set cursor as default arrow
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

                ' Hide the please wait form
                consultando.Hide()

            End If
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' sqlcoon.Dispose()


        End Try

        sqlcoon.Open()

        Try


            For r As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim COMMAND3 As SqlCommand
                Dim READER3 As SqlDataReader
                Dim Query_3 As String

                Query_3 = "select IMOV_CODIGORECBTO from imovimento where IMOV_MOV_IDENTIFICACAO ='" & dgv1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"

                COMMAND3 = New SqlCommand(Query_3, sqlcoon)
                READER3 = COMMAND3.ExecuteReader

                While READER3.Read
                    Dim IMOV_CODIGORECBTO = READER3("IMOV_CODIGORECBTO")
                    'DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "ID"
                    dgv1.Rows(r).Cells(6).Value = IMOV_CODIGORECBTO
                End While
                READER3.Close()

            Next
            dgv1.Sort(dgv1.Columns(6), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            sqlcoon.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Using

End Sub
 
'Function of loading data into Richtextbox

Private Sub preenchimento_rchrelatorio()
Dim entregue = "ENTREGUE"
rchrelatorio.Text += entregue & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine

For r As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
    'richtextbox
    rchrelatorio.Text += dgv1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value & "   "

Next

Dim totalentregue = "TOTAL:  " & dgv1.Rows.Count

rchrelatorio.Text += Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & totalentregue & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine

end sub
```

Result:

[image]

How can the spacing between the lines of this rich text box be increased so that it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any possible way to achieve the result on vb.net ? I saw many forms in C# but I couldn't convert.

Comment: Sending `EM_GETPARAFORMAT` / `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` in C# or VB.Net is ~the same thing. Where are you stuck? On the P/Invoke declarations? + Please, post only code relevant to the question. BTW (unrelated), that's not really the way to add Rows to a DataGridView when you have a source of data coming from a database. Same for this: `rchrelatorio.Text += dgv1.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value & "   "`

Comment: @Jimi, I am a beginner in programming, I know that there are details that need to be adjusted. the dgv is a test trigger just for a future idea it will be removed and the lines will be played directly in the richtextbox. Okay, my doubts are how to do the entire EM_GETPARAFORMAT / EM_SETPARAFORMAT process. I really don't know where to start, could you show a light?

Comment: Sure, I can help you out, BUT you need to show what you have tried to solve the problem yourself. You can find code in VB.Net, not just C#, that performs the same task (and these two language are almost the same). Give it a shot and post back when you have some code (related to this matter alone).

Comment: @Jimi, I posted the answer, being able to solve it, but now I run into another problem, when trying to print or export to richtextbox to pdf it does not go with the formatting that was done, it returns to the default of the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to solve this way:

```
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

 Public Class frm_relatorio_entregas

  Private Structure Paraformat2
    Dim cbSize As UInteger
    Dim dwMask As UInteger
    Dim wNumbering As UInt16
    Dim wEffects As UInt16
    Dim dxStartIndent As Integer
    Dim dxRightIndent As Integer
    Dim dxOffset As Integer
    Dim wAlignment As UInt16
    Dim cTabCount As Int16
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=32)>
    Public rgxTabs() As Integer
    Dim dySpaceBefore As Integer
    Dim dySpaceAfter As Integer
    Dim dyLineSpacing As Integer
    Dim sStyle As Int16
    Dim bLineSpacingRule As Byte
    Dim bOutlineLevel As Byte
    Dim wShadingWeight As UInt16
    Dim wShadingStyle As UInt16
    Dim wNumberingStart As UInt16
    Dim wNumberingStyle As UInt16
    Dim wNumberingTab As UInt16
    Dim wBorderSpace As UInt16
    Dim wBorderWidth As UInt16
    Dim wBorders As UInt16
End Structure


<DllImport("user32", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As Paraformat2) As Integer
End Function


Const EM_LINEFROMCHAR As Integer = &HC9
Const EM_LINEINDEX As Integer = &HBB

Const EM_SETPARAFORMAT As Integer = &H447
Const PFM_LINESPACING As Integer = &H100

 Public Sub SelLineSpacing(ByVal rtbTarget As RichTextBox, ByVal SpacingRule As Byte, Optional ByVal LineSpacing As Integer = 20)

    Dim Para As New Paraformat2

    With Para
        ReDim .rgxTabs(31)

        .cbSize = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(Para))
        .dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING
        .bLineSpacingRule = SpacingRule
        .dyLineSpacing = LineSpacing
    End With

    Dim result As Integer = SendMessage(New HandleRef(rtbTarget, rtbTarget.Handle), EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 1, Para)

    If result = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("EM_SETPARAFORMAT Failed")
    End If
End Sub

   Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' some dummy text to test with
    rchrelatorio.AppendText("2323" & vbCrLf)
    rchrelatorio.AppendText("2323" & vbCrLf)
    rchrelatorio.AppendText("2323" & vbCrLf)
    rchrelatorio.AppendText("2323" & vbCrLf)

    ' optionally select existing text
    ' so as to apply changes to the existing text
    ' as well as future text
    rchrelatorio.SelectAll()

    Dim s As String
    s = InputBox("Insert a RULE number (0 to 5)")

    ' SpacingRule
    ' Type of line spacing. To use this member, set the PFM_SPACEAFTER flag in the dwMask member. This member can be one of the following values.
    ' 0 - Single spacing. The dyLineSpacing member is ignored.
    ' 1 - One-and-a-half spacing. The dyLineSpacing member is ignored.
    ' 2 - Double spacing. The dyLineSpacing member is ignored.
    ' 3 - The dyLineSpacing member specifies the spacingfrom one line to the next, in twips. However, if dyLineSpacing specifies a value that is less than single spacing, the control displays single-spaced text.
    ' 4 - The dyLineSpacing member specifies the spacing from one line to the next, in twips. The control uses the exact spacing specified, even if dyLineSpacing specifies a value that is less than single spacing.
    ' 5 - The value of dyLineSpacing / 20 is the spacing, in lines, from one line to the next. Thus, setting dyLineSpacing to 20 produces single-spaced text, 40 is double spaced, 60 is triple spaced, and so on.


    Dim ruleNum As Byte

    ' returns ruleNum as the number input by the user,
    ' or 255 if user input is bad
    If Not Byte.TryParse(s, ruleNum) Then ruleNum = 255

    Select Case ruleNum
        Case 0 ' Single spacing.
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum)

        Case 1 ' One-and-a-half spacing.
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum)

        Case 2 ' Double spacing.
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum)

        Case 3 ' Spacing in Twips (1440 twips = 1 inch) : ignores spacing less than Single Spacing
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum, 720)

        Case 4 ' Spacing in Twips (1440 twips = 1 inch) : allows spacing less than Single Spacing
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum, 72)

        Case 5 ' Spacing in 20ths of a line (40 = Double Spacing : 100 = 5 line Spacing)
            SelLineSpacing(rchrelatorio, ruleNum, 100)

        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("rule number must be between 0 amd 5")
    End Select

End Sub

 End Class
```

With the code above, at the moment when the richtextbox (rchrelatorio) is filled with the text and then the button is pressed, it generates a dialog box where it asks the spacing size between 0 and 5, and then just run to celebrate.

Important detail.

a problem if in case you want to print the formatted content, you will have to use a shipping method that does not change the configured richtextbox formatting.

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).